# .NET MVC - Collection properties should be read only Change to be read-only by removing the property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, code-analysis

I have a controller that uses two classes. One is called IndexModel and the other IndexViewModel.
I pass the IndexViewModel into the IndexModel constructor.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new IndexModel(new IndexViewModel());
    var vm = model.GetViewModel();
    return View("Index", vm);
}
```

Here is the view model class. Notice that the setter is private.

```
public class IndexViewModel
{
    public IList<SelectListItem> SelectListItems { get; private set; }
    public IndexViewModel()
    {
        this.SelectListItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
    }
}
```

Here is the Model. When GetViewModel is called the SelectListItems list is populated and the view model returned.

```
public class IndexModel
{
    private IndexViewModel vm;

    public IndexModel(IndexViewModel IndexViewModel)
    {
        this.vm = IndexViewModel;
    }

    public IndexViewModel GetViewModel()
    {
        this.FillSelectListItems();
        return vm;
    }

    private void FillSelectListItems()
    {
        // this data is pulled in from another class that queries a database...
        var data = ...
        foreach (var itm in data)
        {
            vm.SelectListItems.Add(new SelectListItem()
            {
                Value = itm.Id.ToString(),
                Text = itm.Text,
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I would appreciate any comments on how this is currently structured, but my main questions are:

Is it bad practice to write a bunch of methods, like FillSelectListItems(), that alter collection data and don't return a result?

Should I make the setter public so I can just return a list from my method and set the view model property that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you have to gain by making it private? A headache... make it public :)

There aren't any problems using view models in other view models... Imagine having a blog post... BlogPostViewModel... you would expect it to also have comments right? BlogPostViewModel > CommentViewModel

```
public class BlogPostViewModel
{
    public string BlogPostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public List<CommentViewModel> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

Now when you render that, on your `PostsController`, at `Posts/{id}`, the view `Posts/Index.cshtml` would be rendered, and your comments can be rendered inside a partial view...

```
// Take this as pseudo code as there's some syntatic errors (can't be asked to open VS)
@for(int i = ... i < Model.Comments.Length... i++){
    this.Html.Partial("_CommentsPartial.cshtml, Model.Comments[i])
}
```

On another note, if you wanted, you could pass your Model to the view as a JSON object as well without with this neat little hack... In your controller action...

```
this.ViewBag.Json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject<TViewModel>(viewModel);
```

And in your view just pick it backup...

```
<script> var json = @this.ViewBag.Json </script>
```

Hopefully this has provided some insight with regards to the purpose these View Models serve...

Comment: I think the reason I thought it better to keep setters private was because of this Code Analysis warning: `Collection properties should be read only Change 'IndexViewModel.SelectListItems' to be read-only by removing the property setter.` Although leaving the collection public seems to have no other negative side affects for me so I guess I can just ignore the warning here. Thanks!

Comment: The reason that it's saying that is because you're not accessing the property from a scope that is higher up the ladder yet... Once you do, that warning will disappear. It's good that you have Code Analysis on as it can help you keep your code clean, but it'll assume your current code state as final and provide you advice based on that.